# Dictionary entries management with Glib

Tags: parsing, hashtable, glib

I'm dealing with a dbus response which looks like as follow:

```
 struct {
     object path "/object/path"
     array [
        dict entry(
           string "A"
           variant                   string "a"
        )
        dict entry(
           string "B"
           variant                   array [
                 string "none"
              ]
        )
        dict entry(
           string "C"
           variant                   string "c"
        )
  ]
```

}

I'm using glib ver. < 2.4 and I need to parse the structure above. I've tried almost everything in order to create an GHashTable, but with no success.
Could you please help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: GLib has had a Hashtable forever so that's probably not your problem... But 2.3 was released in 2003 which is roughly stone age: If I remember correctly D-Bus didn't even exist as an actual implementation at that point -- GLib certainly had no integration with it. You might be using dbus-glib (a library separate from GLib)... but assuming it too is ten years old: you can't expect someone to write example code for ancient, already deprecated libraries. If you want help you'll have to show your work: what you tried, what works, what doesn't.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Basically I have used gdbus-codegen to generate client code for a service that use DBus. Then I've called the proxy to call one method and I got the structure above (achieved with a dbus-send) contained in a GVariant *. I need to parse such response in order to put the various fields in my own object.

Comment: So... the GLib version in the original post is a typo?

Comment: Actually isn't. I'm using something like 2.38.

Comment: Heh, 2.4 is about ten years older than 2.38. If you fix the version number in the post, the question starts making more sense (you should still show your work, but at least people won't pass it by thinking "that can't be right").

Answer (score 0):

Add this parser function in your program:

Arguments to be passed are to the parser function are :

1st: Dictionary - a{sv}

2nd: map reference -So that no need to create the map variable on the stack.

```
void recursive_parser(GVariant *arg_config, map<string, void *> &vec)
{
  GVariantIter iter;
  GVariant *child;
  gchar *key;

 g_variant_iter_init (&iter, arg_config);
 while (g_variant_iter_next (&iter, "{sv}", &key, &child))
 {
    if(g_variant_is_container(child))
    {
      recursive_parser(child, vec);
    }
    else
    {
      if(g_variant_type_equal(g_variant_get_type(child),G_VARIANT_TYPE_STRING))
      {
         gchar *val = g_variant_get_string(child,NULL);
         vec.insert(make_pair<string,void*>(key,val)); 
      }
      if(g_variant_type_equal(g_variant_get_type(child),G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32))
      {
         gint32 *val = g_variant_get_int32(child);
         vec.insert(make_pair<string,void*>(key,val)); 
      }
    }
 }


}
```

This code works for even glib version < 2.4 :-)